# How to apply a color palette generated by material.io to an app using Material Components for the web?

Tags: sass, material-design, material-components, material-components-web

I have a color palette image, which was created by a designer using tools at material.io. This palette includes color hexes for the following:

- Surface, Light and Dark (shown at the top of the palette)
- Primary (plus hues for 50, 100, 200, etc..., 900)
- Secondary (plus hues)

The image also includes what appear to be contrast percentages for black and white text on the mid points and extremes of each color swatch.

[image: Color Palette]

From the material docs I've looked at, it appears the way to customize a theme is by setting SCSS variables such as `$mdc-theme-surface`, `$mdc-theme-primary` and `$mdc-theme-secondary` before importing components, which I have tried. However, the hues of the primary and secondary colors generated don't match those on the generated palette. What additional variables need to be set in order to apply this theme?

Comment: There are several other variables depending on the outcome you are looking for. Check out the [Theming Guide](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/theming/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. That was one of the docs where I discovered that those three variables I mentioned above. They successfully set the primary and secondary colors but the hue variants are different from the image embedded above. What else do I need to get the correct hues? Surely there's some standard process for converting a palette generated by Google's own tools into code, no?

Comment: The remaining colors are automatically calculated once you set the 3 variables noted in your question. To the best of my knowledge, the only way to override the auto-calculated result is to manually alter the other variables and classes mentioned in the theming docs at that link (and even then, we often have had to style individual components at a more granular level to get the color palette consistency we are looking for). In my opinion, color theming in MDC is far from mature and not very easy.

Comment: Thanks. If you want to make that into an answer, I'll take it.

Comment: Going to leave it as is and hope that someone has a better solution to share here.

Comment: how were you able to generate the color palatte for scss using the primary and secondary colors , did you use some library for this ..